# Where define new global variable in Prestashop

Tags: variables, prestashop, constants, prestashop-1.6

The file defines.inc.php contains multiple globals variables but if I want to define new variable which file is the best ?

If I update Prestashop the file defines.inc.php is reset and I loose my global variable.

Maybe in settings.inc.php but this file is not versioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a file `config/defines_custom.inc.php` next to `config/defines.inc.php`. At startup Prestashop checks if this file exists. If it exists then it is included before the default one.

You can find the related code in `config/config.inc.php` :

```php
$currentDir = dirname(__FILE__);

/* Custom defines made by users */
if (is_file($currentDir.'/defines_custom.inc.php')) {
    include_once($currentDir.'/defines_custom.inc.php');
}
require_once($currentDir.'/defines.inc.php');
```

This way you can for example set mode dev on without touching the default file:

```php
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

And in the default file, this define will not occur:

```php
if (!defined('_PS_MODE_DEV_')) {
    define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my version of Prestashop (1.6.1.X) this following code is not included :  include_once($currentDir.'/defines_custom.inc.php');

Comment: @alexandrebru Then you must have modified something because it does exist. https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.1.x/config/config.inc.php#L30

Comment: @TheDrot Yes I find the commit : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/commit/146f0676d5e1fc51d7edcdf46b192988ccbe4660

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create your own module (maybe a 'dummy' module :)), and declare there your global variables.

For example create a module called 'mymodule', the main file `mymodule.php` should be:

```
// Here you can define your global vars
define('MY_CUSTOM_VAR', 100);

class MyModule extends MyModule
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         // See documentation
    }

    public function install(){ return parent::install(); }
}
```

So you can update your PrestaShop version without problems losing your global vars ;)